# How to merge multiple values from multiple columns into one row?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this table:

[image]

I need to convert it to (with parenthesis as well):

```
row_nbr - row_label                     - default_order
10      - TOTAL ACCOUNTABLE GROSS       - (1, 3)
12      - DEDUCTIBLE TERMS              - (3)
20      - TOTAL DEDUCTIBLE TERMS        - (3)
34      - AMOUNT DUE (UNRECOUPED)       - (4)
36      - ACCOUNTABLE GROSS             - (2)
41      - TOTAL CONTINGENT COMPENSATION - (3)
```

I could have more than twice of the same row_nbr.

In this case the 10 is there twice, but I could have 3 10's, 4 12's, etc.

I kind of started the pivot table but honestly, even by looking at the Microsoft site, I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

```
select row_nbr, row_label, default_order
from #temp
pivot
(
  max(row_nbr)
  for default_order in (default_order)
) piv;
```

Anyone care to help?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of sql-server you have? if it's 2017 then you may check this new function to concatenate string using group by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: unfortunately its 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Vinit says, you can use the string_agg function in 2017, but if you're at least on 2005 you can use a horrible, torturous XML generator:

```
SELECT  row_nbr
       ,row_label
       ,default_order = '(' +
            STUFF( 
            (SELECT ', ' + CAST(default_order AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM        #temp
            WHERE       row_nbr = t.row_nbr
            ORDER BY    default_order
            FOR XML PATH('') ,
                ROOT('MyString'),
                TYPE ).value('/MyString[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
            + ')'
FROM    #temp t;
```

You can read more about it in [this blog post](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path/)

Comment: thanks for this but I'm getting an error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

Comment: The Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' error is because you are trying to concatenate ',' with an integer value.
Cast it to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOTS are definitely wonky to get a grip on. Fortunately, in this case, while you *could* use one as an intermediate step, it's not necessary. PIVOT will take each value and put it into a corresponding distinct column, and what you're wanting is a single column, with them all concatenated together. Like I said, you *could* do the pivot, then just concatenate all the generated columns together, but that's way more work than is needed.

On 2014, the easiest way to do this is using `FOR XML`. Russell Fox's answer pretty much covers how that technique works (although there are a few variants on how you can do that should you so choose).

If you know definitively the values are all integers, you can save a bit of typing and omit the `type` and `value` operators, as those are only necessary when you have to escape certain XML characters in string fields

```
select
    row_nbr,
    row_label,
    default_order,
    stuff
    (
        (
            select concat(',', default_order)
            from #temp i
            where i.row_nbr = o.row_nbr
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '' 
    )

from #temp o
```